# Default lock screen comes up in few devices after my lock screen app

Tags: lockscreen, android

I have disabled the default pattern/PIN lock using the following code in my lock screen app.

```
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
k1 = km.newKeyguardLock("IN");
k1.disableKeyguard();
```

Also, i have used the `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD.`

It is working fine in my Moto G. But, few devices are showing the default Pattern lock after my lock screen. How can i fix it? What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD`, you may need: 
`FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`, 
`FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` 
and 
`FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON` also.

i.e.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: If i use FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON, at times the screens getting turned on frequently. How could i avoid this?